# Как сделать снимок всей страницы сайта на платформе Android?

Tags: android, поиск-программ

Имеется ли какой-нибудь софт позволяющий сделать снимок всей страницы сайта на платформе Android?

Comment: вам в Software Recommendations

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не связан с тематикой SO.